# ExtJS 4.0.x : edit a grid in a popup view

Tags: extjs, javascript-framework

I want to edit a grid in a view and I do not know how to open the window or how to load the data in the form of the form window.

Do you help? thank you

i Try :

```
Ext.create('MG.view.UAForm', {
    recordData : record.getData()
}).show();
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to get grid store instance and add/delete/update the record and set to the store. for more understanding, Please refer below link for your queries.

in the link you can able to see an example which contain what u require.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/application_architecture

Thanks